# A method to find the inconsistency or variation in the data

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I am running an experiment (it's an image processing experiment) in which I have a set of paper samples and each sample has a set of lines. For each line in the paper sample, its strength is calculated which is denoted by say '**s**'. For a given paper sample I have to find the variation amongst the strength values '**s**'. If the variation is above a certain limit, we have to discard that paper.

1) I started with the Standard Deviation of the values, but the problem I am facing is that for each sample, order of magnitude for **s** (because of various properties of line like its length, sharpness, darkness etc) might differ and also the calculated Standard Deviations values are also differing a lot in magnitude. So I can't really use this method for different samples.

Is there any way where I can find that suitable **limit** which can be applicable for all samples.

I am thinking that since I don't have any history of how the strength value should behave,( for a given sample depending on the order of magnitude of the strength value more variation could be tolerated in that sample whereas because the magnitude is less in another sample, there should be less variation in that sample) I first need to find a way of baselining the variation in different samples. I don't know what approaches I could try to get started.

Please note that I have to tell variation between lines within a sample whereas the **limit** should be applicable for any good sample.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a set of samples. Then, for each sample you want to do two things: 1) compute a descriptive metric and 2) perform outlier detection. Both of these are vast subjects that require some knowledge of the phenomenology and statistics of the underlying problem. However, below are some ideas to get you going.

1. **Compute a metric**

   - [**Median Absolute Deviation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation). If your sample strength **s** has values that can jump by an order of magnitude across a sample then it is understandable that the standard deviation was not a good metric. The standard deviation is notoriously sensitive to outliers. So, try a more robust estimate of dispersion in your data. For example, the MAD estimate uses the median in the underlying computations which is more robust to a large spread in the numbers.
   - [**Robust measures of scale**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale). Read up on other robust measures like the Interquartile range.
2. **Perform outlier detection**

   - [**Thresholding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)). This is similar to what you are already doing. However, you have to choose a suitable threshold for the metric computed above. You might consider using another robust metric for thresholding the metric. You can compute a robust estimate of their mean (e.g., the median) and a robust estimate of their standard deviation (e.g., 1.4826 * MAD). Then identify outliers as metric values above some number of robust standard deviations above the robust mean.
   - [**Histogram**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) Another simple method is to histogram your computed metrics from step #1. This is non-parametric so it doesn't require you to model your data. If can histogram your metric values and then use the top 1% (or some other value) as your threshold limit.
   - [**Triangle Method**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28047-gray-image-thresholding-using-the-triangle-method) A neat and simple heuristic for thresholding is the triangle method to perform binary classification of a skewed distribution.
   - [**Anomaly detection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) Read up on other outlier detection methods.